# How should I choose the knot sequence when using B-splines as a basis for solving a PDE?

Tags: pde, basis-set, b-spline

I'm looking to solve the Schrödinger equation with a basis made of a tensor product of basis splines. A number of papers describe calculations made with a program designed this way, but they never describe how they got the knot sequence they use to define the basis.

**How does one go about choosing a knot sequence for a set of B-splines to be used as a basis for the solution of a PDE?**

Comment: Could you add a link to one of the papers you mention, just for reference?

Comment: @Paul: There's an example [here](http://iopscience.iop.org/0953-4075/46/11/112001/pdf/0953-4075_46_11_112001.pdf), but it's paywalled.